# ReDirect subfolder link to another sub-folder and force SSL

Tags: redirect, htaccess, directory, ssl, https

My wordpress is installed in a subfolder, for example: test, so my urls look like http://example.com/test/product/buy-product-a/ etc..

1. Now I have installed another wordpress in subfolder, for example: live, so I hope all my links could redirect to the same structure, for example: http://example.com/live/product/buy-product-a/
2. 2nd requirement is I have installed a SSL, all links should change to "https". So actually the new link should be https://example.com/live/product/buy-product-a/

How to redirect in htaccess? Please help, thanks!